# bzr security, how to prevent push overwrite

Tags: bazaar

How can I set the file permissions of a `bzr` repository to allow somebody to push to the branch, but not be allowed to overwrite it?

That is, currently a user can completely overwrite the branch by doing `bzr push --overwrite --use-existing-dir target_repo_branch`. This is obviously not a good thing as the revision history then appears to be completely lost.

So how can I prevent that operation while allowing the normal correct push operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option append_revisions_only on the branch configuration to true.

Or you can use bzr init --append-revisions-only when creating the branch. That would avoid overwriting the history.

You can look here

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.3/en/user-reference/configuration-help.html

Regards